# Gerund or Continuous

Tags: gerunds, reported-speech, continuous

I want to know what will be the direct speech of this sentence. Also what are travelling and willing? are they continuous form or gerund?

> She asked if anyone travelling to India would be willing to carry the bag along.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there anyone (who is) traveling to India (who) would be willing to carry the bag along?"

-*who is traveling to India* is a [restrictive relative clause](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/relative-clauses/) which is functioning as an adjectival modifying the antecedent *anyone*. Since the antecedent is the subject of the main clause it may be reduced to the gerund phrase by dropping the relative pronoun and "be":

> *traveling to India*

-*who would be willing to carry the bag along* is another restrictive clause and as it also modifies the subject may also drop the relative pronoun *who* and the verb "be":

> *willing to carry the bag along*

The original sentence could have been:

> "Is there anyone traveling to India willing to carry a bag along?"

or (more formal)

> "Is there anyone who is traveling to India who would be willing to carry a bag along?"

Comment: Is there anyone *kidnapped* by orcs who needs a helping hand?

Comment: @TRomano I'm not sure. What have the Trolls been saying?

Comment: Or "Would anyone travelling to India be willing to carry a bag along?" (although this use of "along" sounds odd to me - I'd say "with them" instead, or maybe even omit it altogether).